# Dynamic Imports In React With Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, import

I have a lot of different icons that I need to load into the wwwroot folder so that the passed back icon or url can use the icon in the react project. This gets complicated as there are three different icons for each allegen and this needs dynamically imported as some might not be present and isn't worth loading in.

I was wondering if there is a decent way of doing what I'm doing below without needing one massive switch statement based on the file and folder name to pass back the required icon from this helper file. I have tried loading the icons in dynamically in the commented out box but have had no luck with it so far.

When trying to import via the commented code I get the error.

```js
import CeleryAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/celery/celery_amber_200x200.png';
import CeleryRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/celery/celery_red_200x200.png';
import CeleryGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/celery/celery_grey_200x200.png';
import CrustacensAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/crustacens/crustacena_amber_200x200.png';
import CrustacensRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/crustacens/crustacena_red_200x200.png';
import CrustacensGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/crustacens/crustacena_grey_200x200.png';
import EggsAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/eggs/eggs_amber_200x200.png';
import EggsRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/eggs/eggs_red_200x200.png';
import EggsGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/eggs/eggs_grey_200x200.png';
import FishAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/fish/fish_amber_200x200.png';
import FishRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/fish/fish_red_200x200.png';
import FishGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/fish/fish_grey_200x200.png';
import LupinAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/lupin/lupin_amber_200x200.png';
import LupinRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/lupin/lupin_red_200x200.png';
import LupinGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/lupin/lupin_grey_200x200.png';
import MilkAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/milk/milk_amber_200x200.png';
import MilkRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/milk/milk_red_200x200.png';
import MilkGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/milk/milk_grey_200x200.png';
import MolluscsAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/molluscs/molluscs_amber_200x200.png';
import MolluscsRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/molluscs/molluscs_red_200x200.png';
import MolluscsGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/molluscs/molluscs_grey_200x200.png';
import MustardAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/mustard/mustard_amber_200x200.png';
import MustardRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/mustard/mustard_red_200x200.png';
import MustardGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/mustard/mustard_grey_200x200.png';
import PeanutAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/peanut/peanut_amber_200x200.png';
import PeanutRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/peanut/peanut_red_200x200.png';
import PeanutGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/peanut/peanut_grey_200x200.png';
import SesameAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/sesame/sesame_amber_200x200.png';
import SesameRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/sesame/sesame_red_200x200.png';
import SesameGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/sesame/sesame_grey_200x200.png';
import SoyaAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/soya/soya_amber_200x200.png';
import SoyaRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/soya/soya_red_200x200.png';
import SoyaGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/soya/soya_grey_200x200.png';
import SuplphurDioxideAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/sulphurdioxide/sulphurdioxide_amber_200x200.png';
import SuplphurDioxideRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/sulphurdioxide/sulphurdioxide_red_200x200.png';
import SuplphurDioxideGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/sulphurdioxide/sulphurdioxide_grey_200x200.png';
import TreenutAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/treenut/treenut_amber_200x200.png';
import TreenutRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/treenut/treenut_red_200x200.png';
import TreenutGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/treenut/treenut_grey_200x200.png';
import WheatAmber from '../../../assets/img/allergens/wheat/wheat_amber_200x200.png';
import WheatRed from '../../../assets/img/allergens/wheat/wheat_red_200x200.png';
import WheatGrey from '../../../assets/img/allergens/wheat/wheat_grey_200x200.png';

const fetchComp = (name, status) => {
    // this works because its passing the icon directly back
    return TreenutGrey;
};

// const fetchComp = (name, status) => {
//   import(`../../../assets/img/allergens/${name}/${name}_${status}_200x200.png`)
//     .then(() => console.log('Loaded'), (err) => console.log('Error', err));
//   return `../../../assets/img/allergens/${name}/${name}_${status}_200x200.png`;
// };

const getStatusIcon = (name, status) => {
  switch (status) {
  case 'Contains':
    return fetchComp(name, 'red');
  case 'MayContain':
    return fetchComp(name, 'amber');
  case 'DoesNotContain':
    return fetchComp(name, 'grey');
  case 'NotProvided':
    return fetchComp(name, 'grey');
  default:
    return fetchComp(name, 'grey');
  }
};

const findAllergenIcon = ({ name, status }) => {
  const nameToLower = name.toLowerCase();
  switch (nameToLower) {
  case 'pecan':
    return getStatusIcon('treenut', status);
  default:
    return getStatusIcon(nameToLower, status);
  }
};

export default findAllergenIcon;
```